# Magento 2.0 Custom Module - Adding custom tab with new fields in Product Form

Tags: php, magento, tabs, magento-2.0

I have successfuly made a custom tab with custom fields inside it following this tutorial:  [datasheat](http://www.datasheat.com/tutos/6)

However, I need the implementation to be on my own "module".  Does any of you know how the **catalog_product_new.xml** and **Tabs.php** be implemented if ever I move them onto my own module directory? Sorry this is my first ever post and I am not sure if I should copy paste the long codes in my post but I'll do you needed.

THis is my first time to code in Magento as I do Opencart stuff, but was unfortunately tasked with porting an OC plugin to Magento.

Thanks guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Namespace Name:** Test

**Module Name:** ProductTabs

1. First go to the admin panel of your Magento store and then navigate to Stores -> Product. Click on Add New Attribute and create new Attribute. (Set Attribute label DEMO and Attribute code demo)
2. Now go to Stores -> Attribute Set and Add Attribute Set.
3. Now click on your Attribute Set and dragged unassigned Attribute (which you have created in first step) to Product Details and click Save.
4. Now go to your product edit page in admin panel and change the attribute name and template name which you have created in first and second step.
5. In app/code/Test/ProductTabs/etc/module.xml paste this code. 
   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Test_ProductTabs" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
   </config>`
6. In app/code/Test/ProductTabs/registration.php, paste this code. 
   `<?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Test_ProductTabs',
    __DIR__
    );`
7. In app/code/Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml, paste this code. 
   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_config uration.xsd">
   <body>
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="demo.tab"  template="Test_ProductTabs::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
   <arguments>
   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom  Tab</argument>
   </arguments>
    </block>
   </referenceBlock>
   </body>
   </page>`
8. Now in app/code/Test/ProductTabs/view/frontend/templates/custom_tab.phtml, paste this code.
   `<?php 
   $product = $block->getProduct();
   ?>
   <h1 style="color: #00aeed"><?php echo $product->getData('demo'); ?></h1>`
9. Now lauch your product page.